# How to create com.microsoft.graph.models.Message with attachment?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to send email with inline attachment using MS Graph. I know how to send email without attachment but when I'm trying to send message with attachment I don't know how can I add this attachment to the message.
Here is my code:

```
// recipients
Recipient recipient = new Recipient();
EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress();
emailAddress.address = "tom@mail.com";
recipient.emailAddress = emailAddress;
List<Recipient> recipients = List.of(recipient);

// body
ItemBody body = new ItemBody();
body.contentType = BodyType.HTML;
body.content = "<html><body>my image:<br><img src='cid:my_image_CID'></body></html>";

// inline image
Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
attachment.isInline = true;
attachment.contentType = ".png";
attachment.id = "my_image_CID";
//attachment.contentBytes                  - I DON'T SEE THIS FIELD...

// message
Message message = new Message();
message.subject = "my subject";
message.body = body;
message.toRecipients = recipients;
//message.attachments =                    ??? - how to create this object?
```

there are examples in the internet that I can set attachment.contentBytes but I don't see this attribute.
For the message I can set attachments object which is of type

```
AttachmentCollectionPage
```

but I don't know how can I create this object.

I'm using the following versions:

```
Microsoft Graph Java SDK » 5.42.0
Microsoft Graph Java Core SDK » 2.0.14
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [FileAttachment](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/4139f70beba18877fbb2dc307700df006d303edb/src/main/java/com/microsoft/graph/models/FileAttachment.java) which extends `Attachment` and has property `contentBytes`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below in C# to add an inline attachment/s (I know it's not Java but you should be able to reproduce the same result):

```
var message = new Message
{
    Subject = seq.Subject,
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = "your email body"
    },
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "email@address.com"
            }
        }
    },
    HasAttachments = true,
    Attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage()
    {
        new FileAttachment
        {
            Name = "someImage.png",
            ContentId = "someImage.png",
            ContentBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("path to someImage.png"),
            IsInline = true,
            ContentType = "image",
        },
        new FileAttachment
        {
            Name = "anotherImage.jpg",
            ContentId = "anotherImage.jpg",
            ContentBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("path to anotherImage.jpg"),
            ContentType = "image",
        }
    }
}
```